# IOS - Sending http requests when application is in background after triggered from UNNotificationAction

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notification-content-extension

Im using a notification content extensions with customized action (Accept, Dismiss).
When pressing dismiss I'm trying to send an https request to my server. 
Keep getting -1009 error (The Internet connection appears to be offline).

Application is setup to use background modes.

Is it even possible to run any network calls in the background?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_timeextending_your_app_s_background_execution_time

Answer (score 2):

My bad.
The problem was calling the completionHandler without waiting for my rest response.